# Scrolling not working in Firefox, I have a table which loadsMore when user scrolls down but it stops for firefox

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, firefox, scroll

Scrolling not working in Firefox, I have a table which loadsMore when user scrolls down but it stops for firefox. If i zoom out then the scrolling works properly. Any ideas what I can do?.

Works perfectly in all other browsers except Firefox

```
function TableWaypoint({ onLoadMore = () => null, offset, pending, columnsCount }) {
  return (
    <>
      <TableRow>
        <TableCell colSpan={columnsCount} className={styles.lastCell}>
          {offset !== 0 && <Waypoint onEnter={onLoadMore} />}
        </TableCell>
      </TableRow>
      {pending &&
        Array.from(new Array(3)).map((row, index) => (
          <TableRow key={index}>
            {Array.from(new Array(columnsCount)).map((Cell, index) => (
              <TableCell key={index}>
                <Skeleton variant="rect" />
              </TableCell>
            ))}
          </TableRow>
        ))}
    </>
  )
}


           <TableWaypoint
               columnsCount={columns.length}
               onLoadMore={onLoadMore}
               offset={data.length}
               pending={pending}
            />
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you kindly provide a minimal example in order to show the code you have already written and help people to better understand your problem? This is a nice guide about it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Ok I added code